# Does Google still pay attention to the <!-- google_ad_section_start --> hints?

Tags: google, google-adsense

Does Google still pay attention to the `<!-- google_ad_section_start -->` and `<!-- google_ad_section_end -->` or `<!-- google_ad_section_start(weight=ignore) -->` hints nowadays? I've searched google but haven't found a clear answer yet.

Is there a 100% correct and unambiguous answer in this regard that can be relied upon?

Comment: Pay attention to them for what?  Where to put ads in the page?

Comment: No, of course not. These markers indicate areas that Google should pay special attention to when assessing which ads to display (in terms of content). Google yourself after it. My question is addressed to those who know these markers and I would like to know if they are still necessary or ignored by Google in the meantime.

Comment: Does no one know the answer?